# select record by date in SQL without stored date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to select a record in `SQL` between 2 dates without stored date in field?

Comment: can you explain your question more??? with example

Comment: You can't unless the date is stored somewhere

Comment: i have a table with 100 record that stored ID, name, family in this. i want select records that adding between 10/2/2014 to 10/4/2014

Comment: @MasoudHosseini You can't of you only have those columns on your table

Comment: so should stored date?

Comment: you need to add a new column to your table with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as a default value

Comment: tanks a lot for help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't keep an internal record of when a row was added, modified, or deleted. If you're not tracking this are part of the row format then what you're asking is not possible.

Comment: tanks a lot, probably he wants we search this and understand this impossible!

Comment: If, however, he gives you a data model that HAS a date field in it - then it's totally possible. There are other RDBMS systems that do track this, however SQL Server is not one of them.